# Mybatis static method for object creation

Tags: mybatis

I have a class with a private constructor and a public static factory method:

```
public class Car {
    private final String name;
    private final boolean isCheap;

    private Car(String name, boolean cheap) {
        this.name = name;
        isCheap = cheap;
    }

    public static Car createCheap(String name) {
        return new Car(name, true);
    }
}
```

How do I tell MyBatis to use `createCheap` method instead of constructor to create new objects when it retrieves results from DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom [`ObjectFactory`](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#objectfactory).

Here is an example implementation that subclasses the built-in [`DefaultObjectFactory`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/reflection/factory/DefaultObjectFactory.java).

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory;

public class MyObjectFactory extends DefaultObjectFactory{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public <T> T create(Class<T> type,
      List<Class<?>> constructorArgTypes,
      List<Object> constructorArgs) {
    if (Car.class == type) {
      String name = (String) constructorArgs.get(0);
      return (T) Car.createCheap(name);
    }
    return super.create(type, constructorArgTypes, constructorArgs);
  }
}
```

You need to tell MyBatis to use the custom object factory instead of the default one. See the linked documentation for how.
If you are using mybatis-spring-boot, there are several different ways. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/).

The mapping may require a result map with constructor-mapping (in other words, auto-mapping won't work).
If you use XML mapper, it would look as follows.

```xml
<resultMap type="pkg.Car" id="carRM">
  <constructor>
    <arg column="name" javaType="string"/>
  </constructor>
</resultMap>
```

With annotation, you can use `@Arg`.

```java
@Arg(column = "name", javaType = String.class)
@Select("select name, ...")
List<Car> getCars();
```